# Extract text from a column by delimiters Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So far I've only used powerquery to clean and automate files, and i want to step up my game and move to python, but I'm having some issues and have no one to ask so I'm coming to you for help, I'm completely new to python and learning based off youtube videos and the python for data analysis book so please bear with me for a moment.

To learn, I've been working on a project using a sample csv file, the file cover several dates and has multiple columns with different data, what I want to do is split the file into different csv based on the date on the column "DateFull" which has the dates with a ***yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00*** format and name the new csv files with the date.

Looking at youtube videos I came up with this piece of code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample_file.csv")

split_dates = df['DateFull'].unique()

for date in split_dates:
    df1 = df[df['DateFull'] == date]
    split_file_name ="Samplefile_" + str(date) + ".csv"
    df1.to_csv(split_file_name,index=False)
```

But when i run it it errors out because it tries to bring the whole name and is not acceptable. I've been looking into the *split* method to separate the **DateFull** column at the whitespace, but I don't know how to incorporate that into the code.

It's obvious that I don't have any idea of how the structure or logic of the code should be but my plan was to use the `df['DateFull'].str.split()` command to create two new columns, one with just the date, and one with the 00:00:00 part, then remove the last one and the original **DateFull** to have the trimmed date column replace it and use that one to split the csv.

I know I'm probably overcomplicating it and there's an easier way to do it, maybe just removing the time part from the original column. If that's possible it would be amazing to know how to do it. but I'd also like how to do it with my approach, since I would be practicing more methods even though the resulting code will be redundant

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: This is a really well-asked question. One recommendation - in the future provide the full text of the error you receive when you try to run this code. That greatly assists with debugging.

Comment: Hey, sorry I only thought about it after posting the question, this is the error I get "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Sample_file_2020-10-13 00:00:00.csv'". Also worth noting that the DATEFULL column is not a date time dtype, just object, not sure if that's important

Comment: Often that means that Python is treating it as a string, or `str`. Which means your use of the `.split()` function to solve this problem makes good sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the `split()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

To do this with `split()`:

```py
str(date).split(" ")[0]
```

This splits on the whitespace and return the first (0 indexed) value in the resulting list. With this change your `for` loop would look like this:

```py
for date in split_dates:
    df1 = df[df['DateFull'] == date]
    split_file_name ="Samplefile_" + str(date).split(" ")[0] + ".csv"
    df1.to_csv(split_file_name,index=False)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I'm aware this might be a very basic and dumb question but this is a point where I still get confused, and it is where should I add that line on the code so that it replaces the DateFull column or adds a new one to the dataframe?

Comment: Just updated my answer with the suggested answer included in your `for` loop.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I understand the logic of it now that you said it, but I guess I have a long way to get there by myself. Thank you so much for your help!